# I can't assign values to the "List Collection" in my class

Tags: c#, list, class, methods, overloading

This is my class That contains two List collections that will store input that is sent over from my main form.  As of right now it have no compiling errors in my class, however I am not sure if it is correct.  What it is suppose to do is receive input and display it when called.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

    namespace EmployeeRoster
    {

            public class Employee
            {
                List<string> name = new List<string>();
                List<int> iDnumber = new List<int>();


            public void setEmployeeName( List < string> employeenames, string names)
            {
                employeenames.Add(names);
                employeenames = name;
            }

            public List <string> getEmployeeName()
            {
                return name;
            }

            public void setEmployeeNumber( List < int > employeeId, int numbers)
            {
                employeeId.Add(numbers);
                employeeId = iDnumber;
            }


            public List<int> getEmployeeName()
            {
                return iDnumber;
            }
        }
}
```

I am Trying To assign names to my list that I have created in my class above,  However I am trying this code below and I am receiving 2 errors

1. // Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'
2. // Error No overload for method 'setEmployeeName' takes 1 arguments

What Is the correct way to send arguments into Class in order to fill my list?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace EmployeeRoster
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employee chart = new Employee();
            List < Employee > names = new List < Employee > ();


            text1.Text = names; // Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EmployeeRoster.Employee>' to 'string'  

            chart.setEmployeeName(names); // Error No overload for method 'setEmployeeName' takes 1 arguments   


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text1.text = Convert.ToString(names);`

You can convert it on the fly like that.

I don't believe you need to pass the collection over to the class. The class can instantiate and add the strings to the collection for you.

Comment: So I do not need to call my overloaded method in my class?  Oh and The Convert did work, thanks but will this store the users input in the list collection created in my class